# How to retrieve the value of options from a select drop-down using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, drop-down-menu, webdriver

In the given code, I need the list of the value of the "value" attribute for each of the options in the select drop-down :

```
<select id="myselect">
<option value="val1">Some Text</option>
<option value="val2">Some Text</option>
<option value="val3">Some Text</option>
<option value="val4">Some Text</option>
<option value="val5">Some Text</option>
<option value="val6">Some Text</option>
</select>
```

I want the list of all the values, which is 
{val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6}

Comment: What have you tried already? Please provide some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of values from dropdown list with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662616/how-to-get-list-of-values-from-dropdown-list-with-selenium-and-python)

Comment: try using `Select` you can see an example in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662968/8179099

Answer (score 1):

To create a *List* of all the values of the **value** *attribute* for each of the options with in the `<select>` tag you can use the following *Java* based solution:

```
Select dropDownSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("myselect")));
List<WebElement> dropDownActualValues = dropDownSelect.getOptions();
for(WebElement element:dropDownActualValues)
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute("value"));
```